# Format internet time string (Swift 1.2)

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, format

I'm trying to format a string from internet time to something more readable.

The input I have is something like: `Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:00:00 +0000`

And I'd like to format it into just: `Mon, 27 Apr`

I'm fairly new to Swift so I don't know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```
let unformattedDateString = "Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:00:00 +0000"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
// input format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

// create NSDate from String
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(unformattedDateString)!

// output format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM"

// create String from NSDate
let formattedDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: to read a bit more about the dateformats: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns